# CSS files are empty on Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

[Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) is looking bad right now. No errors in the console, but the following files have no content:

- http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/cso/all.min.css?v=da39a3ee5e6b
- http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/cso/cities.min.css?v=da39a3ee5e6b
- http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/less/organs/ad-units.min.css?v=da39a3ee5e6b
- http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/cso/jobs.min.css?v=da39a3ee5e6b

The CSS on another subdomain works fine though:

- http://cdn.sstatic.net/skins/topbar/topbar.css
- http://cdn.sstatic.net/skins/topbar/favicons.css
- http://cdn.sstatic.net/skins/topbar/favicons.css?v=9858b02449ea

Comment: Same here with google chrome/IE :)

Comment: Yeah, that's *awful*.

Comment: We're on it, fix shortly.

Comment: It's very 90s. https://web.archive.org/web/19961220154510/http://www.yahoo.com/

Comment: Unexpected late participant in [CSS Naked Day](http://naked.threepixeldrift.com/)

Comment: @Hynes status-completed then? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So we just pushed a fix, sorry about that! Here's a breakdown of what went wrong...

We upgraded our local version of [lesscss](http://lesscss.org/) from 1.7 to 2.2. Everything worked just fine. This just uses the in-browser version of LESS.

Next up we updated the version in our build process. We use a custom nodejs build tool called capn-crunch that compiles and minifies our LESS and JS using a heavily parallelised engine. We use lesscss to compile LESS followed by clean-css to minify the result.

It *seemed* to work just fine - the build tool executed successfully with no errors. We checked out the development environment and it looked all good. Then we pushed to production. Oh noes! Everything is broken! Why is it OK on dev?

Turns out an old friend [Monsieur Le Cache](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) bit us; dev was not in a good way either.

So what was the problem?

Between 1.7 and 2.2 there was a minor breaking change in the lesscss API:

From this:

```
        less.render(fileData, options, function (e, css) {
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }

            file.data = new Buffer(css);
            next(null, file);
        });
```

To this:

```
        less.render(fileData, options, function (e, output) {
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }

            file.data = new Buffer(output.css);
            next(null, file);
        });
```

Note the change to the second argument in the event handler. When we instantiated the `Buffer` to pass the result to the next item in the pipeline it passed in an object. Turns out `Buffer` doesn't throw in this case and even then we wouldn't have handled the error correctly.

To fix this issue we've taken a two-pronged approach.

Firstly, improve the error handling in the LESS handler:

```
        var error = null;
        less.render(fileData, options, function (e, output) {
            if (e) {
                error = e;
                return;
            }
            try {
                file.data = new Buffer(output.css);
            }
            catch (e) {
                error = e;
                return;
            }

            if (error != null) {
                throw error;
            }

            next(null, file);
        });

        if (error != null) {
            throw error;
        }
```

This ensures errors bubble out of the pipeline correctly.

Secondly, add an integration test that verifies whether some common CSS and JS has been generated correctly (in this case checking for a zero-length file). This will prevent breaking changes like this making it out to production.

Comment: Priceless bug... and BTW your hair is still on fire. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard it burns eternally!

Answer (score 11):

All over it, will be fixed shortly.

Comment: Time for a spin of the [Wheel of Blame](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelb958/vSfXT/embedded/result/)? ;-)

Comment: It's been spinning for 10 minutes, keeps coming up with the same person :)

Comment: uh oh. Not me again?

Comment: As an information, external job buttons also has no css style :)

Comment: @Sha I blame you cuz you provided the *unofficial* wheel of blame. It will give borked results, use the original one :D

Comment: I will keep on spinning till it's the comunity's fault, guess everybody does that :-)